# What does 'site' in 'site-packages' actually mean?

Tags: python, naming, nomenclature

I've always been a bit curious about the rationale of the naming of `site-packages`. What does `site` mean in this context? I doubt it means 'website', and I've never heard 'site' used in relation to the installation location, or the context of the machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not the only weird term in the Python world. The word "dedent" doesn't seem to exist in the English language, but for Python it seems to be the perfectly valid opposite of "indent".

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - can you give other examples?

Comment: @teukkam - at least it's obvious what dedent means, and it's partially valid, as the 'in' is a well known affix (even if 'de' isn't the opposite of 'in', I would have thought 'outdent' would be more correct)

Comment: From the top of my head, Perl and Ruby use `site` for local module/package/whatever repositories, too. I don't know the origin, but it's not just a Python thing.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose "we've always done it that way" is a good second place to "it's because...".

Comment: @Joe So what do we mean exactly by "site packages"?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava We read the answers below.

Comment: @Joe Ah got it. Thanks anyway. Read the other questions related to site-packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a good question, and I don't know the answer. But I do have heard "site" as a way to name the combination of OS, installed software and/or physical computer. See for example http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html , where they use the term a lot.

Answer (score 12):

I think `site` is used to mean the same thing as `local`, as in `/usr/local/*` - it's those elements that are installed locally/for this site, as opposed to those that are provided by the system.

Answer (score 5):

I have always understood this as short for **on-site** - oposite to **remote**. Probably because those are the packages that are on your machine. That's just my guess, though :)